# Play a byte at time samples audio in java

Tags: java, audio

I'm writing an audio application in java (c++ and assembly) and i need to play continuously an array of ints that are storing the samples of the audio i want out (this must be done in java).

So i need a function that let me put out a sample at time in the audiostream.

```
int sample; //The integer i want to play
while(true)
{

    //here i will modify the array of samples
}
//.....in another thread:
{
   // Here i need a function that plays a samples
    FunctionThatPlaysinteger(sample);

}
```

Comment: You don't want to play *single* samples. You want to use the ["sampled" API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html).

Comment: Specifically, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html#113634 shows how to send arrays of bytes (samples) to the audio output.

Comment: Yes, thanks i'm studyng the javadocs, than if i find a suitable solution i'll post it as a answer! thanks